# How to make automatic page transition in AMP stories?

Tags: amp-html

I have a working stories on [AMP](https://amp.dev/)(Accelerated Mobile pages)  but I couldn't find a documentation about how to make the pages transit automatically with out the user clicking on the story.  For example if I want to show the story for 10 seconds and then show the next page, and then the next after 10 sec . . .

Answer (score 3):

After googling I found the answer in their documentation [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/amp_story_best_practices)

```html
<amp-story-page auto-advance-after="9s">
```